# в таблице нужно обновить вставив подстроку в строку

Tags: php, sql

в таблице нужно обновить столбец `company_workday_slug`. если в записи есть символ ':', нужно вставить перед ним строку '.wd1'

я дошел до такого, что естественно не работает, иначе зачем мне сюда писать ?)
"UPDATE `company` SET `company_workday_slug` = INSERT (`company_workday_slug`, POSITION(`:`, `company_workday_slug`)-1, 0 , `.wd1`)")

например если адрес wmg:WMGUS, то поменять его на wmg.wd1:WMGUS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE company 
SET company_workday_slug = REPLACE(company_workday_slug, ':', '.wd1:')
```

Comment: благодарю за помощь)